# iPhone, can I have a custom UITableView cell and a background image for the table?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'd like to have the contents of my table to scroll around on top of my background image.

or I don't mind if the cells can take chunks of the background image, so that the background remains behind the cells but scrolls with the cells.

Is this possible? if so how ?

I've tried adding an image view and setting my cells and table background colour to clear.

Here's my code.

http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/testback.zip can you have a look ?

Comment: That should work. Post your code.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little?

Specifically, what do you mean by "the background remains behind the cells but scrolls with the cells."?

Comment: It sounds like you're really close. What if you resize your table to be a little smaller than your background? Can you see it then? If so, your table view is probably clipping subviews.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. What do you want to do? have an static background image behind your whole tableview with custom cells? I imagine this table is grouped?

Comment: Your download link is no longer working, and the code inside is necessary for this question and answer to make any sense. Is there any chance you can post the relevant code snippets straight into the question?

Comment: @LarrikJ - The question was asked on Nov 4, '10 & your writing this comment on Mar 12, '11. And the question is already answered by this period. Then why somebody will keep his/her code still active to be downloaded?

Comment: @Sagar I was under the impression that questions and answers should be useful for everyone, not just those originally involved. I'm afraid without any code whatsoever, this question has no shelf life.

Comment: @LarrikJ - You're absolutely correct. I would suggest (you & whole stackoverflow community) to check the answer from Manjunath. He is given the code snippet which is also one of the correct answer of this question. Also PARTH has given the algorithm in more descriptive manner to achieve this. And do check my answer (which has -1 reputation) which demos the shortest way to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated earlier, problem is with your code. From the code-sample (http://kidsmaskfactory.com/code/testback.zip) you've given, you need to do 2 modifications:

1) Change your parent class of RootViewController from UITableViewController to UIViewController.
2) Set the view property of File Owner to your view not to your table view.

After this re-compile & run your code & it should give you following output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the backgroundView of your UITableView to whatever you want - probably a UIImageView with your picture in it.

This will give you a background image. Now the question is how can you make the background image scroll with your table. I'm not sure but there are two posibilities:

1. Since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView -- the backroundView will be scrolled with the rest of the table, and you won't need to do anything.
2. The backgroundView is a separate view which is not derived from UIScrollView. You will then need to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate to intercept changes in scroll position, and manually apply those changes to your backgroundView.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jules Follow the steps below to set the backgound image to tableview. This works!! I have tried it.

**STEP-1**

In your xib put your tableview and allocate it's delegate and datasource fields to File's Owner.

**STEP-2**

Now Drag a imageView on to your tableview and resize it to size of your View. select the image you want to display in the background using the Inspector.

**STEP-3**

Select the imageView and Go to Menu "Layout -> Send to Back"

**STEP-4**

Select your tableview and set background color as "clear color" from the Inspector.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded your test project and here is what I think.

You've made your rootviewcontroller in an odd way.  It's a specialization of UITableViewController, but you've added your own UITableView as a child view, along with your UIImageView.  There is a much easier way.

Your RootViewController should simply be regular UITableViewController-derived class, with no changes to the structure in Interface Builder.  If you want to define your UIImageView in UInterface Builder then drag a UIImageView into the XIB but not as a child of the UITableView.  Make it a top level object.  Hook it up to a new IBOutlet you add in code to RootViewController:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UIImageView* _backgroundImageView;

}
```

Be sure to set the image in the UIImageView in Interface Builder.

In your RootViewController.m file, add the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = _backgroundImageView;
}
```

I modified your test project and posted it here: http://www.codeveloper.com/TestCustomCellWithViewBackground-TomSwift.zip

Answer (score 0):

**step1:** change the RootViewController.h to:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *reportTableView;

}

@end
```

**step2:**

In RootViewController.m:

add this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    reportTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

**step3:**

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

change:

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell"
                                                             owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) 
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) 
        {
            cell = ((ReportCell *) currentObject);
            break;
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

**Step4:**

Go to Nib file

-> set the reportTableView outlet to tableview.

-> set the view outlet to the view.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Put an image view behind the table view. And change the background color to of the UITableView as clear ([UIColor clearColor]).

Comment: I think problem is there in your code. Because this solution is always working. And I found the same solution given by Parth above in more descriptive manner. So I definitely bet problem is in your code.